# Edited features only store edits upon map refresh

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, editing, features

I am setting editing toolbars for features on my map as follows:

```
 for (var graphicNum = 0; graphicNum < graphicList.length; graphicNum++) {
        if (graphicList[graphicNum].symbol != undefined) {
            //Initializing the toolbar to be used for the feature modification process
            moveToolbarLabel = new esri.toolbars.Edit(app.map);
            moveToolbarLabel.activate(esri.toolbars.Edit.MOVE | esri.toolbars.Edit.SCALE | esri.toolbars.Edit.ROTATE, graphicList[graphicNum]);
            allToolbars.push(moveToolbarLabel);
        }
    }
```

When moving or scaling a feature after the scale and rotation points appear the feature reverts to its original state when the mouse is unclicked (Meaning click on scale point, drag to resize, let go and feature goes back to original size). However if the map is then refreshed by zooming in the feature takes on the changes that would have been made when the mouse was dragged. Is there any way to make the feature keep the edits right away rather than having to zoom in/out of the page to see the changes?

Comment: did the answer posted fix your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `FeatureLayer`, which contains your features, you have to refresh manually the layer after perform your edits by calling `featureLayer.refresh();`

You can find more information [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#refresh)